# > and >= at Assembly level

Tags: c, assembly

I two `time_t` variables say start_sec and end_sec. Now I've to perform million operations of finding out whether a given random `time_t` falls in this range.

```
if(given_sec >= start_sec && given_sec <= end_sec) {
    /* given_sec falls in the interval*/
}
```

or

```
start_sec -= -1; //keep it for million comparisons
end_sec += 1; //keep it for million comparisons

if(given_sec > start_sec && given_sec < end_sec) {
    /* given_sec falls in the interval*/
}
```

which one is better?

I guess at the assembly level `je loc; jle loc; jg loc; jge loc`are used to jump. I was wondering if `jg loc; jl loc`save any CPU cycles.

Comment: Just write this in C and let compiler to decide what is better.

Comment: Which platform are we even talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A perfect example of premature optimization at the micro level, worrying about single CPU cycles, that gives you nothing, but obfuscates your code -- `start_sec` and `end_sec` no longer contain the values that the names suggest. And you even optimized it wrong:

```
start_sec -= -1; //keep it for million comparisons
```

This will *add* one to `start_sec`.

Where do the millions of `time_t` values come from? An input file? A database? From the system clock? A random generator? Each of these sources will be magnitudes slower than the comparison. So even if < and > are some CPU cycles faster than <= and >= (for your given instruction set on your given specific CPU), and profiling shows that this loop is in fact your bottleneck, this "optimization" is unlikely to solve this problem. Especially for just a few million comparisons on modern GHz CPUs with billions of cycles per second.

Comment: I made several typos in the initial post. Corrected all of them, apparently all are not being reflected.. Yes, source of time_t is system clock. since app is a server & range is one time load and comparison is for eternity. For serious number crunching saving few CPU cycles wherever possible make sense.

Answer (score 5):

No, they don't save anything and if they were, optimizer would help you anyway.

Comment: @muntoo: if you did that, then chances are good that you don't care about performance.